# Awk: Splitting on 2 or more spaces only

Tags: regex, unix, awk

I'm trying to reformat the output of the `last` command e.g. `last -adn 10 | head -n -2 | awk -F' {2,}' '{ print "USER:",$1,"IP:",$5 }'`.

```
>> last -adn 10 | head -n -2
root     pts/0        Tue Jul 10 13:51   still logged in    10.102.11.34
reboot   system boot  Fri Jun 22 09:37         (18+04:19)   0.0.0.0
```

I would like my output to be something like:

```
>>last -adn 10 | head -n -2 | awk -F' {2,}' '{ print "USER:",$1,"IP:",$5 }'
USER: root IP: 10.102.11.34 TIME: Tue Jul 10 13:51
```

I've tried every method described [here](http://jamesmcdonald.id.au/it-tips/splitting-records-by-multiple-spaces-but-not-single-spaces-using-awk), and I can't figure out why this is not working for me. 
When executing that command, it simply stores the whole line in $1, and the others are blank.

Comment: It works for me with version `GNU Awk 4.0.1`.

Comment: that could be the problem, currently running 3.1.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, gawk does not enable interval expressions. You can enable them with the `--re-interval` flag. Other versions of awk may or may not support them at all.

If you can't enable the flag, you can use a more explicit match. For example:

```
$ echo 'foo  bar baz' |
    awk -F'[[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]]*' '{print $2}'
bar baz
```

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE** based on @WilliamPursell comment/suggestion:

Instead of this:

```
awk -F' {2,}' '{ print "USER:",$1,"IP:",$5 }'
```

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="   *"}{ print "USER:",$1,"IP:",$5 }'
```

seems to be working for me and fixes the shortcoming of my previous solution using `'BEGIN{FS="  "}...` which only split on exactly 2 spaces.

*Note*: `FS` is set to **3 spaces** and an `*`, meaning the last space can occur zero or more times.

Comment: The first would split on 2 or more spaces though, the second would split on exactly 2.

Comment: @AndrewNguyen Ah .. ok, thanks for the feedback. I'll delete my post then.

Comment: @Levon  Don't delete, just modify it to `-F'   *'` (That's 3 spaces and an asterisk, but the html is chomping spaces)

Comment: @WilliamPursell Actuall, why don't ***you*** post this as a valid answer -- after all, it's *your* (correct/working) answer :)

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks .. I will do it for posterity and give you the credit (which really is yours).

Comment: I think that this should be `FS="   *"` (with three spaces - there are currently only two in the answer); although `FS="  +"` (with two spaces) also works.